# Kotlin: Desirealize a Json object that looks like array but not an array in shape

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this array as a server response, and i want to get an array or list from it.

```
    "items": {
        "1614273900": {
            "date": "25-02-2021",
            "open": 12.02,
            "high": 12.02,
            "low": 11.96,
            "close": 11.97
        },
        "1614274200": {
            "date": "25-02-2021",
            "open": 11.98,
            "high": 11.99,
            "low": 11.93,
            "close": 11.95
        },
        "1614274500": {
            "date": "25-02-2021",
            "open": 11.95,
            "high": 11.97,
            "low": 11.91,
            "close": 11.95
        },
        "1614274800": {
            "date": "25-02-2021",
            "open": 11.95,
            "high": 11.97,
            "low": 11.92,
            "close": 11.93
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how can i get an array of items from it? I'm trying using GSON library but it not has a structured as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own TypeAdaper for this. Also why don't you parse it as it is? It's a Map<String, CustomDate> like below. You can parse it as a Map, and the normalize the data inside a getter

```
data class CustomDate(
    @SN("date") val date: String?,
    @SN("open") val open: Double,
    @SN("high") val high: Double,
    @SN("low") val low: Double,
    @SN("close") val close: Double){

        var ts: Long = 0 // this is going to be calculated from keys
}

data class Response(
    @SN("items") val itemsMap: Map<String, CustomDate>
){
    val itemsList get() = itemsMap.map{ // convert each key/value to the value
        it.value.ts = it.key.toLongOrNull() ?: 0 //convert key to long (I assume it's timestamp
        it.value // value as mapped item
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, don't know that approach, it's al i need

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it into map.

```
private fun parse(jsonString: String): Item {
   return Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Item::class.java)
}

data class Item(
    val item: LinkedHashMap<String, Obj>
)

data class Obj(
    val date: String,
    val open: Double,
    val high: Double,
    val low: Double,
    val close: Double
)
```